# SQL based on data in column, move to other column

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table in SQL as described below.
This described in Check-in and Check-out time of people.
The table is generated by a system and can't be changed unfortunatly.

| Name | TimeStamp | In-Out |
| --- | --- | --- |
| John | 30-01-2024 08:00 | I |
| John | 30-01-2024 14:00 | O |

For the desired situation, I want to make a view in SQL that outputs the format below.
TimeStamp IN (Where [In-Out] = I) and TimeStamp OUT (Where [In-Out] = O) are always between 0 to 16 hours difference.

| Name | TimeStamp IN | Timestamp OUT |
| --- | --- | --- |
| John | 30-01-2024 08:00 | 30-01-2024 14:00 |

Does anyone have an idea how to approach this?

Comment: tell me the datatype of TimeStamp and Timestamp OUT column

Comment: Can you have missing entries? An "in" without a matching "out"?

Comment: Use lead over order by timestamp to find out time for each in time. Use lead again to ensure that the next row is an out time and current row is an in time.

Answer (score 2):

This can be done using the conditional aggregation using the aggregate function `MAX()` :

```
SELECT Name,
       MAX(CASE
           WHEN [In-Out] = 'I' THEN TimeStamp
           ELSE NULL
       END) AS TimeStampIN,
       MAX(CASE
           WHEN [In-Out] = 'O' THEN TimeStamp
           ELSE NULL
       END) AS TimestampOUT
FROM mytable
GROUP BY Name;
```

Results :

```
Name    TimeStampIN             TimestampOUT
John    2024-01-30 08:00:00.000 2024-01-30 14:00:00.000
```

[Demo here](https://dbfiddle.uk/F8ZIJ3SQ)

---

If there are multiple pairs, and each pair of data corresponds to the same day,then it is necessary to group by both the name and the date :

```
SELECT Name,
       MAX(CASE
           WHEN [In-Out] = 'I' THEN TimeStamp
           ELSE NULL
       END) AS TimeStampIN,
       MAX(CASE
           WHEN [In-Out] = 'O' THEN TimeStamp
           ELSE NULL
       END) AS TimestampOUT
FROM mytable
GROUP BY Name,
         CAST(TimeStamp AS DATE)
```

[Demo here](https://dbfiddle.uk/2fKIMhZo)

Comment: I'm guessing he wants every pair to be a row but who knows

Comment: Good remark @siggemannen, I have covered this scenario

Answer (score 1):

A simple self-join should be all you need.  Something like this:

```
SELECT i.first_name, i.time_stamp, o.time_stamp
FROM yourtable i
INNER JOIN yourtable o ON o.first_name = i.first_name
WHERE o.in_out = 'O' AND i.in_out = 'I'
AND DATEDIFF(hh, i.time_stamp, o.time_stamp) <= 16
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use something along the lines of:

```sql
SELECT Name, arrival.Timestamp as [Timestamp IN], dep.Timestamp as [Timestamp OUT]
from table as arrival
inner join table as dep on arrival.Name = dep.Name  -- an ID Field would be nice
where arrival.In-Out = '|' and dep.In-Out = 'O'
```

You first select everything from just the Arrivals and then put it together with the matching Departures with the same names.
You would get a lot of problems, when for example 2 Johns are in the table.

Comment: i changed the alias in an edit, thx for the reminder.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT Name, TimeStamp AS [TimeStamp IN], 
    LEAD(TimeStamp) OVER (ORDER BY <OrderingColumn>) AS  AS [TimeStamp OUT]
FROM <TABLE>
WHERE In-Out = 1
```

Comment: A good answer contains an explanation

Comment: Didn't downvote but there is a flaw, the where clause will remove the "out" entries before you get to calculat the lead.

Comment: Yeah. WHERE clause has to be placed in an outer query as below.

`SELECT *
FROM 
    (SELECT Name, TimeStamp AS [TimeStamp IN], 
        LEAD(TimeStamp) OVER (ORDER BY <OrderingColumn>) AS  AS [TimeStamp OUT] , In-Out 
FROM <TABLE> ) A
WHERE In-Out = 1`

Answer (score -1):

[image]

Below will create a new view in your table please note TimeStamp is in DATETIME

```
CREATE VIEW CheckInOutView AS
SELECT
    Name,
    MAX(CASE WHEN `In-Out` = 'I' THEN TimeStamp END) AS `TimeStamp IN`,
    MAX(CASE WHEN `In-Out` = 'O' THEN TimeStamp END) AS `TimeStamp OUT`
FROM new_table
GROUP BY Name, DATE(TimeStamp)
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT `In-Out`) = 2;
```